# Get data of jQuery datatable whose status is CMM Approved

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a jQuery datatable with many records. In this there are several columns also of which one column name is `STATUS`. In that status there are many status information.

So what I want is, I want the data of status column whose status is `CMM Approved`.

Below is the code for the same:

```html
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive3"><div class="dataTables_scroll"><div class="dataTables_scrollHead" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; border: 0px; width: 100%;"><div class="dataTables_scrollHeadInner" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 1968px; padding-right: 0px;"><table class="sites myTable table table-striped table-bordered nowrap dataTable no-footer" ui-jq="dataTable" ui-options="dataTableOpt" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="grid" style="margin-left: 0px; width: 1968px;"><thead><tr role="row"><th class="select-checkbox sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 20px;" aria-label=""></th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 42px;" aria-label="Action: activate to sort column ascending">Action</th><th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 103px;" aria-label="SAP ID: activate to sort column ascending">SAP ID</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 132px;" aria-label="NETWORK ENTITY ID: activate to sort column ascending">NETWORK ENTITY ID</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 122px;" aria-label="SITE NAME: activate to sort column ascending">SITE NAME</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 103px;" aria-label="ASSESTS COUNT: activate to sort column ascending">ASSESTS COUNT</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 91px;" aria-label="SERVICE CODE: activate to sort column ascending">SERVICE CODE</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 426px;" aria-label="SHORT DESC: activate to sort column ascending">SHORT DESC</th><th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 78px;" aria-label="SITE STATUS: activate to sort column ascending">SITE STATUS</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 68px;" aria-label="RFE1 DATE: activate to sort column ascending">RFE1 DATE</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 62px;" aria-label="RFR DATE: activate to sort column ascending">RFR DATE</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 163px;" aria-label="VENDOR: activate to sort column ascending">VENDOR</th><th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 114px;" aria-label="STATUS: activate to sort column descending" aria-sort="ascending">STATUS</th></tr></thead></table></div></div><div class="dataTables_scrollBody" style="position: relative; overflow: auto; width: 100%;"><table id="certifyEFO" class="sites myTable table table-striped table-bordered nowrap dataTable no-footer" ui-jq="dataTable" ui-options="dataTableOpt" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="grid" aria-describedby="certifyEFO_info" style="width: 100%;"><thead><tr role="row" style="height: 0px;"><th class="select-checkbox sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 20px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;" aria-label=""><div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height:0;overflow:hidden;"></div></th><th class="sorting" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 42px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;" aria-label="Action: activate to sort column ascending"><div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height:0;overflow:hidden;">Action</div></th><th class="sorting_asc" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 103px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;" aria-label="SAP ID: activate to sort column ascending"><div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height:0;overflow:hidden;">SAP ID</div></th><th class="sorting" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 132px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;" aria-label="NETWORK ENTITY ID: activate to sort column ascending"><div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height:0;overflow:hidden;">NETWORK ENTITY ID</div></th><th class="sorting" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 122px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;" aria-label="SITE NAME: activate to sort column ascending"><div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height:0;overflow:hidden;">SITE NAME</div></th><th class="sorting" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 103px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;" aria-label="ASSESTS COUNT: activate to sort column ascending"><div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height:0;overflow:hidden;">ASSESTS COUNT</div></th><th class="sorting" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 91px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;" aria-label="SERVICE CODE: activate to sort column ascending"><div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height:0;overflow:hidden;">SERVICE CODE</div></th><th class="sorting" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 426px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;" aria-label="SHORT DESC: activate to sort column ascending"><div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height:0;overflow:hidden;">SHORT DESC</div></th><th class="sorting_asc" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 78px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;" aria-label="SITE STATUS: activate to sort column ascending"><div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height:0;overflow:hidden;">SITE STATUS</div></th><th class="sorting" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 68px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;" aria-label="RFE1 DATE: activate to sort column ascending"><div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height:0;overflow:hidden;">RFE1 DATE</div></th><th class="sorting" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 62px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;" aria-label="RFR DATE: activate to sort column ascending"><div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height:0;overflow:hidden;">RFR DATE</div></th><th class="sorting" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 163px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;" aria-label="VENDOR: activate to sort column ascending"><div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height:0;overflow:hidden;">VENDOR</div></th><th class="sorting_asc" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 114px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;" aria-label="STATUS: activate to sort column descending" aria-sort="ascending"><div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height:0;overflow:hidden;">STATUS</div></th></tr></thead><tbody id="datagrdbody"><tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="select-checkbox"></td><td><a class="actionIcon" id="discripancy"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></a></td><td class="sorting_3">I-AP-AMRP-ENB-6000</td><td>INAPAMRPAMRPTW6001</td><td>AMARAPURAM</td><td>0</td><td></td><td></td><td class="sorting_2">ACTIVE</td><td>09/07/2019</td><td> </td><td>Delton Infra P Limited - 396475</td><td class="sorting_1">ASSIGNED TO VENDOR</td></tr><tr role="row" class="even"><td class="select-checkbox"></td><td><a class="actionIcon" id="discripancy"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></a></td><td class="sorting_3">I-AP-AMRP-ENB-6001</td><td>INAPAMRPXXXXTW6003</td><td>BASAVANAHALLI</td><td>0</td><td>3310744</td><td>SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS / SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS</td><td class="sorting_2">ACTIVE</td><td>09/07/2019</td><td> </td><td>Delton Infra P Limited - 396475</td><td class="sorting_1">ASSIGNED TO VENDOR</td></tr><tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="select-checkbox"></td><td><a class="actionIcon" id="discripancy"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></a></td><td class="sorting_3">I-AP-AMRP-ENB-6002</td><td>INAPAMRPXXXXTW6002</td><td>THAMMADEHALLI</td><td>0</td><td>3310744</td><td>SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS / SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS</td><td class="sorting_2">ACTIVE</td><td>09/07/2019</td><td> </td><td>Delton Infra P Limited - 396475</td><td class="sorting_1">ASSIGNED TO VENDOR</td></tr><tr class="disableRow even" role="row"><td class="select-checkbox"></td><td><a class="actionIcon" id="discripancy"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></a></td><td class="sorting_3">I-AP-AGLI-ENB-6001</td><td>INAPAGLIXXXXTW6002</td><td>INAGALORE</td><td>0</td><td>3310744</td><td>SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS / SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS</td><td class="sorting_2">ACTIVE</td><td>09/07/2019</td><td> </td><td>Delton Infra P Limited - 396475</td><td class="sorting_1">CMM APPROVED</td></tr><tr class="disableRow odd" role="row"><td class="select-checkbox"></td><td><a class="actionIcon" id="discripancy"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></a></td><td class="sorting_3">I-AP-AGLI-ENB-6002</td><td>INAPAGLIXXXXTW6003</td><td>KODIHALLI</td><td>0</td><td>3310744</td><td>SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS / SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS</td><td class="sorting_2">ACTIVE</td><td>09/07/2019</td><td> </td><td>Delton Infra P Limited - 396475</td><td class="sorting_1">CMM APPROVED</td></tr><tr class="disableRow even" role="row"><td class="select-checkbox"></td><td><a class="actionIcon" id="discripancy"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></a></td><td class="sorting_3">I-AP-AGLI-ENB-9004</td><td>INAPHDPRXXXXTW0007</td><td>Thumakunta Check Post</td><td>0</td><td>3310744</td><td>SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS / SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS</td><td class="sorting_2">ACTIVE</td><td>09/07/2019</td><td> </td><td>Delton Infra P Limited - 396475</td><td class="sorting_1">CMM APPROVED</td></tr><tr class="disableRow odd" role="row"><td class="select-checkbox"></td><td><a class="actionIcon" id="discripancy"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></a></td><td class="sorting_3">I-AP-AGLI-ENB-9005</td><td>INAPAGLIXXXXTW0003</td><td>P.bedagira village</td><td>0</td><td>3310744</td><td>SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS / SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS</td><td class="sorting_2">ACTIVE</td><td>09/07/2019</td><td> </td><td>Delton Infra P Limited - 396475</td><td class="sorting_1">CMM APPROVED</td></tr><tr class="disableRow even" role="row"><td class="select-checkbox"></td><td><a class="actionIcon" id="discripancy"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></a></td><td class="sorting_3">I-AP-AGLI-ENB-9006</td><td>INAPAGLIXXXXTW0004</td><td>H D HALLI THANDA</td><td>0</td><td>3310744</td><td>SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS / SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS</td><td class="sorting_2">ACTIVE</td><td>09/07/2019</td><td> </td><td>Delton Infra P Limited - 396475</td><td class="sorting_1">CMM APPROVED</td></tr><tr class="disableRow odd" role="row"><td class="select-checkbox"></td><td><a class="actionIcon" id="discripancy"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></a></td><td class="sorting_3">I-AP-AGLI-ENB-9007</td><td>INAPAGLIAGLITW0001</td><td>sira road</td><td>0</td><td>3310744</td><td>SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS / SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS</td><td class="sorting_2">ACTIVE</td><td>09/07/2019</td><td> </td><td>Delton Infra P Limited - 396475</td><td class="sorting_1">CMM APPROVED</td></tr><tr class="disableRow even" role="row"><td class="select-checkbox"></td><td><a class="actionIcon" id="discripancy"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></a></td><td class="sorting_3">I-AP-AMLD-ENB-6000</td><td>INAPAMLDAMLDTW0001</td><td>AMIDALAGONDI</td><td>0</td><td>3310744</td><td>SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS / SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS</td><td class="sorting_2">ACTIVE</td><td>09/07/2019</td><td> </td><td>Delton Infra P Limited - 396475</td><td class="sorting_1">CMM APPROVED</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div>
```

Also the fiddle is provided for the same.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3an8pqkd/1/)

Comment: Can't you filter out your dataset and get the result?

Comment: that's what I am stuck too, please help

Comment: How are you pulling data? Are you using Ajax call to pull data?

Comment: no not ajax, you can see function `DisableViewGroupSummaryData` in fiddle. I want that in a var all the data

Comment: Do you need the array of items where "STATUS" is "CMM Approved"?

Comment: yes, I want that

Comment: Okay. Let me try. By the way, why are you using 2 tables?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205276/discussion-between-nkb-and-mayank-patel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to `filter` the DataTable and get the `JSON` array. Though there is no such direct solution to your need, we can do it with some `jQuery` trick.

What I have done in my fiddle is that I am first getting all the `rows` from `DataTable` and have removed unnecessary data from this array.

Once this is complete, I am getting the list of columns using `jQuery`.

The final step is to create the final `JSON` array by looping through rows and columns. Hence, in the end, `filtered_data` is your desired output.

Kindly let me know if this is not what you are looking form.

Also, You can check the following fiddle.

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xv9ewuna/1/)

```js
var table = $('#certifyEFO').DataTable();
var raw_data = table.rows().data().toArray();
for (var i in raw_data){
 raw_data[i].splice(0,2);
}
var columns=[];
$("#certifyEFO thead tr th").each(function(){
        columns.push(this.innerHTML.replace('\n', '').replace('                                ', ' ').trim());
    });
columns.splice(0, 2);
// console.log(raw_data);
var final_raw_data = [];
raw_data.filter(function(item){
 var row_item = {}
 item.filter(function(item_inner, index){
   row_item[columns[index]] = item_inner;
    return item_inner;
  });
  final_raw_data.push(row_item);
  return item;
});
var filtered_data = final_raw_data.filter(function(item){
 return item["STATUS"].toLowerCase() == 'cmm approved';
})
console.log(filtered_data);
// Create new DataTable from filtered_data
var columns_for_new_dt = [];
columns.filter(function(item){
 columns_for_new_dt.push({ "data" : item, "title" : item })
});
table = $('#new_data_table').DataTable( {
        columns: columns_for_new_dt,
        data:    filtered_data
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<table id="certifyEFO">
    <thead>
                        <tr role="row">
                            <th class="select-checkbox sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 20px;"
                                aria-label=""></th>
                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
                                style="width: 42px;" aria-label="Action: activate to sort column ascending">Action
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
                                style="width: 103px;" aria-label="SAP ID: activate to sort column ascending">SAP ID
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
                                style="width: 132px;" aria-label="NETWORK ENTITY ID: activate to sort column ascending">
                                NETWORK ENTITY ID
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
                                style="width: 122px;" aria-label="SITE NAME: activate to sort column ascending">SITE
                                NAME
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
                                style="width: 103px;" aria-label="ASSESTS COUNT: activate to sort column ascending">
                                ASSESTS COUNT
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
                                style="width: 91px;" aria-label="SERVICE CODE: activate to sort column ascending">
                                SERVICE CODE
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
                                style="width: 426px;" aria-label="SHORT DESC: activate to sort column ascending">SHORT
                                DESC
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
                                style="width: 78px;" aria-label="SITE STATUS: activate to sort column ascending">SITE
                                STATUS
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
                                style="width: 68px;" aria-label="RFE1 DATE: activate to sort column ascending">RFE1 DATE
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
                                style="width: 62px;" aria-label="RFR DATE: activate to sort column ascending">RFR DATE
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
                                style="width: 163px;" aria-label="VENDOR: activate to sort column ascending">VENDOR
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="certifyEFO" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
                                style="width: 114px;" aria-label="STATUS: activate to sort column descending"
                                aria-sort="ascending">STATUS
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
    <tbody id="datagrdbody">
                    <tr role="row" class="odd">
                        <td class="select-checkbox"></td>
                        <td><a class="actionIcon" id="discripancy"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></a></td>
                        <td class="sorting_3">I-AP-AMRP-ENB-6000</td>
                        <td>INAPAMRPAMRPTW6001</td>
                        <td>AMARAPURAM</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="sorting_2">ACTIVE</td>
                        <td>09/07/2019</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Delton Infra P Limited - 396475</td>
                        <td class="sorting_1">ASSIGNED TO VENDOR</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr role="row" class="even">
                        <td class="select-checkbox"></td>
                        <td><a class="actionIcon" id="discripancy"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></a></td>
                        <td class="sorting_3">I-AP-AMRP-ENB-6001</td>
                        <td>INAPAMRPXXXXTW6003</td>
                        <td>BASAVANAHALLI</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>3310744</td>
                        <td>SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS / SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS</td>
                        <td class="sorting_2">ACTIVE</td>
                        <td>09/07/2019</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Delton Infra P Limited - 396475</td>
                        <td class="sorting_1">ASSIGNED TO VENDOR</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr role="row" class="odd">
                        <td class="select-checkbox"></td>
                        <td><a class="actionIcon" id="discripancy"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></a></td>
                        <td class="sorting_3">I-AP-AMRP-ENB-6002</td>
                        <td>INAPAMRPXXXXTW6002</td>
                        <td>THAMMADEHALLI</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>3310744</td>
                        <td>SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS / SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS</td>
                        <td class="sorting_2">ACTIVE</td>
                        <td>09/07/2019</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Delton Infra P Limited - 396475</td>
                        <td class="sorting_1">ASSIGNED TO VENDOR</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="disableRow even" role="row">
                        <td class="select-checkbox"></td>
                        <td><a class="actionIcon" id="discripancy"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></a></td>
                        <td class="sorting_3">I-AP-AGLI-ENB-6001</td>
                        <td>INAPAGLIXXXXTW6002</td>
                        <td>INAGALORE</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>3310744</td>
                        <td>SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS / SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS</td>
                        <td class="sorting_2">ACTIVE</td>
                        <td>09/07/2019</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Delton Infra P Limited - 396475</td>
                        <td class="sorting_1">CMM APPROVED</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="disableRow odd" role="row">
                        <td class="select-checkbox"></td>
                        <td><a class="actionIcon" id="discripancy"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></a></td>
                        <td class="sorting_3">I-AP-AGLI-ENB-6002</td>
                        <td>INAPAGLIXXXXTW6003</td>
                        <td>KODIHALLI</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>3310744</td>
                        <td>SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS / SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS</td>
                        <td class="sorting_2">ACTIVE</td>
                        <td>09/07/2019</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Delton Infra P Limited - 396475</td>
                        <td class="sorting_1">CMM APPROVED</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="disableRow even" role="row">
                        <td class="select-checkbox"></td>
                        <td><a class="actionIcon" id="discripancy"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></a></td>
                        <td class="sorting_3">I-AP-AGLI-ENB-9004</td>
                        <td>INAPHDPRXXXXTW0007</td>
                        <td>Thumakunta Check Post</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>3310744</td>
                        <td>SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS / SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS</td>
                        <td class="sorting_2">ACTIVE</td>
                        <td>09/07/2019</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Delton Infra P Limited - 396475</td>
                        <td class="sorting_1">CMM APPROVED</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="disableRow odd" role="row">
                        <td class="select-checkbox"></td>
                        <td><a class="actionIcon" id="discripancy"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></a></td>
                        <td class="sorting_3">I-AP-AGLI-ENB-9005</td>
                        <td>INAPAGLIXXXXTW0003</td>
                        <td>P.bedagira village</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>3310744</td>
                        <td>SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS / SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS</td>
                        <td class="sorting_2">ACTIVE</td>
                        <td>09/07/2019</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Delton Infra P Limited - 396475</td>
                        <td class="sorting_1">CMM APPROVED</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="disableRow even" role="row">
                        <td class="select-checkbox"></td>
                        <td><a class="actionIcon" id="discripancy"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></a></td>
                        <td class="sorting_3">I-AP-AGLI-ENB-9006</td>
                        <td>INAPAGLIXXXXTW0004</td>
                        <td>H D HALLI THANDA</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>3310744</td>
                        <td>SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS / SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS</td>
                        <td class="sorting_2">ACTIVE</td>
                        <td>09/07/2019</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Delton Infra P Limited - 396475</td>
                        <td class="sorting_1">CMM APPROVED</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="disableRow odd" role="row">
                        <td class="select-checkbox"></td>
                        <td><a class="actionIcon" id="discripancy"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></a></td>
                        <td class="sorting_3">I-AP-AGLI-ENB-9007</td>
                        <td>INAPAGLIAGLITW0001</td>
                        <td>sira road</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>3310744</td>
                        <td>SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS / SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS</td>
                        <td class="sorting_2">ACTIVE</td>
                        <td>09/07/2019</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Delton Infra P Limited - 396475</td>
                        <td class="sorting_1">CMM APPROVED</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="disableRow even" role="row">
                        <td class="select-checkbox"></td>
                        <td><a class="actionIcon" id="discripancy"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></a></td>
                        <td class="sorting_3">I-AP-AMLD-ENB-6000</td>
                        <td>INAPAMLDAMLDTW0001</td>
                        <td>AMIDALAGONDI</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>3310744</td>
                        <td>SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS / SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS</td>
                        <td class="sorting_2">ACTIVE</td>
                        <td>09/07/2019</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Delton Infra P Limited - 396475</td>
                        <td class="sorting_1">CMM APPROVED</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
</table>
<b>NEW DataTable from filtered_data</b>
<table id="new_data_table"></table>
```

**EDIT**

Also, You can check the following fiddle which has new Data Table for filtered data..

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xv9ewuna/1/)

Comment: let me try and check

Comment: Sure. Please note, I have removed some style from your HTML which you can add back.

Comment: Yes. I am here.